# How can I perform a search over only my direct messages in Slack?

Tags: slack

I'd like to perform a search (e.g., "webapps") over my direct messages.  How can I perform a search over only my direct messages in Slack?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reddit user [PixelatorOfTime](https://www.reddit.com/user/PixelatorOfTime) [pointed me](https://redd.it/viljjx) to the solution:

To perform a search over only the direct messages that I received or sent in Slack:

```
is:dm SEARCHTERMHERE
```

To perform a search over only the direct messages that I sent in Slack:

```
from:me is:dm SEARCHTERMHERE
```